# Accidental Exclude From VisualSVN

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2008, visualsvn

I accidentally selected "Exclude from Subversion" from the VisualSVN menu on my VS2008 project root.  I have not updated or committed so I still have both the repository and local versions available.

I need to know how to re-include the excluded project.

Comment: Isn't there an "Exclude from Subversion exclusion list" option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VisualSVN should have functionality to allow you to revert changes. If you do this from your project root, you should be able to undo the exclusion.

All that the "Exclude from Subversion" selection should have done was update the property `svn:ignore` on the directory in question (you can verify this by checking for modifications on your project). Reverting that specific change should correct the problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you much, as ignorant as it may sound I hadn't considered Reverting. Thank you thank you thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Revert the project file using subversion.

Comment: Your were right as well, if I could mark two answers for this question you'd have #2!  Thank you for the advice none-the-less!

Comment: You're welcome, subversion always helps you out, even if you happened to commit a mistake you can "revert changes FROM this revision" in the history. If you want to get back to a previous revision "revert changes TO this revision". Then even after a new commit you get a good version again in the repository.

Answer (score 1):

(Flippant comments above aside) The ignored files and folders are listed in the `svn:ignore` property of the parent folder. I don't know much about VisualSVN, but you should be able to edit that property through its interface; or at least you should be able to do it through the command line `svn.exe`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I had found the svn:ignore property but after removing it SVN indicated it still wanted to delete the project directory.

Comment: In the normal case, reverting the parent folder (what you did to solve the problem) should be equivalent to removing the `svn:ignore`. You must've done something else as well.